# Click on navigation anchor tag does not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, anchor

I have bootstrap navigation bar

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a class="nav-link" id="nav-welcome" href="/welcome">
            <i class="icon-coffee visible-phone"></i>
            <span>Welcome</span>
        </a>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-index" href="/">
            <i class="icon-home visible-phone"></i>
            <span class="hidden-phone">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>


    <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a class="nav-link" id="nav-prospects" href="/prospects">
            <i class="icon-time visible-phone"></i>
            <span>Prospects</span>
        </a>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a class="nav-link" id="nav-contacts" href="/contacts">
            <i class="icon-leaf visible-phone"></i>
            <span class="hidden-phone">Contacts</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav li a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #E1E5E5;
    text-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

The link is working if i click on the navigation except last word of span element.
Lets say, if i click on 's' on Contacts link, it does not work.

Comment: It works fine in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cec2p/), do you have any custom CSS rules on elements containing the `<ul>`? Please post them if you do.

Comment: Thanks. Added my css. Also i set width of link to auto. It does not work.

Comment: add `display:block;` to the CSS above.

Comment: *display:block;* does not work. Interestingly the css :active styles is shown when i click. But it does not take it to href